# EF POCO objects: remove circular reference

Tags: entity-framework, poco, circular-reference

I have extracted POCO object from my data model, there is a circular reference (i.e Customer has contacts and Contacts has Customer)..I just want to have one-direction reference i.e Customer has contacts ..How do i remove the referecne of Contacts to Customer.

I could go to each Objects and remove the referecnce or make it private but that is not fexlible...because each time I update the model I need to update the reference as well. Is there any easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

No, once you remove the navigational property from the entity, when you "Update Model from Database", EF will **not** put it back in.

Only if you delete and re-add the entity will it put it back.

So, remove the *Customer* navigational property on the *Contact* entity and you'll be fine.